# Signal Angular component to update

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

Using AngularJS Components what is the best way to signal to a component to update?

Say I have `myComponent` and I want to tell it to update its data, how would I achieve that? I'd prefer not to use `$emit` or `$broadcast` if possible instead opting for something as analogous to Angular2 as possible.

Currently I pass in a control object with callbacks that the component implements but I do not like this approach.

Another concept I had was to signal via the one-way binding mechanism but it feels very hacky.

```
<my-component update="$ctrl.shouldUpdate"></my-component>
```

My controller would then do

```
function update(){
    this.shouldUpdate = Math.rand();
}
```

Is there a better, more modern Angular way to do this?

**Clarification**

Some people asked for clarification:

Imagine you have two components

- peopleList
- personEditor

Because of how they are used, they both get a list of "people" from the server so have no shared (bound), common list of people.

Imagine then that the personEditor changes a persons name and saves it to the server.

How would one go about telling the peopleList component that it needs to update

Comment: Please, provide more information on how this is supposed to work. MCVE would be great. It can be & binding (it is coherent with A2/4 events) or RxJS.

Comment: Is person editor a child of peopleList?

Comment: @MikeFeltman It is at the moment yes, but `peopleList` is used in many places so I don't really want a tightly coupled solution i.e. using `require` to the parent or something as I wouldnt want to affect its use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In the person editor component I would add an optional reference to the parent list using bindings. Something like:

```
    bindings: { parentList: '<?' }
```

Then when you update in the person editor component check for the presence of parentList and update accordingly. You could set it up so you specify the method in the parent to call and pass it the updated data.

Comment: Thats actually quite a nice simple idea, I think I was dismissing the obvious and went for a more complicated solution!

Comment: @Petr Your comment is on a deleted answer I believe. The OP clarified his question since that answer was posted and I went ahead and deleted it. Can I suggest you delete your comment to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect time for a service that is responsible for getting a list of people from the server.  Both of your pieces would use the same service to get information.  Then if one updates something, the other (which is using the same data source) would automatically see the updates.  For example:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .service("peopleService", peopleService);

peopleService.$inject = ["$http"];
function peopleService($http) {
    var svc = this;

    svc.people = [];

    svc.getPeople = getPeople;
    svc.updatePerson = updatePerson;

    return svc;

    function getPeople() {
        //$http call to get people
    }

    function updatePerson(person) {
        //some call to the server

        //update the javascript objects
    }
}
```

Then both of your `peopleEditor` and `peopleList` can reference the same data source.  Just include the `peopleService` into the controller(s) and use that as the data source.  For example:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('mainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['peopleService'];
function mainController(peopleService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.people = peopleService.people;

    return vm;
}
```